# Byte Code off-card verifier for cap file

Tags: bytecode-manipulation, javacard

I need to verify a Java Card programme (a cap file) using an off-card byte code verifier.
I have manually modify the informations in the cap file and i want to verify if the new cap file is well type.

I try to use the com.sun.javacard.scriptgen.CAP.verifyCAP() methode. I send valid and invalid cap files but the result is always equal to 0.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the CLI tools of the Java Card development tools? If you require a program, then you might just directly call the main method...

Comment: Yes, but i try with a Java Program but the result is the same.
`capFile.verifyCAP()` or `com.sun.javacard.offcardverifier.Verifier` return the same result.

Comment: So, the off-card verifier require JAR cap file but i sent an no JAR cap file. I modify my programe to generate JAR cap files.
Then i can't use the `int com.sun.javacard.scriptgen.CAP.verifyCAP()` methode. The result is always 0.
Then i try to use the `com.sun.javacard.offcardverifier.Verifier.verifyCap(FileInputStream arg0, String arg1, Vector arg2)` method but i don't know what are the arguments i have to use.

Comment: I try to use the `com.sun.javacard.offcardverifier.Verifier.main(String[] arg0)` method. It's work well, i have obtain the answer i want. But when i send an invalid cap file, that's stop my program.
In fact in the byte code of this method i read `329  invokestatic java.lang.System.exit(int) : void [18]`

Comment: Maybe try to run it in a separate JVM, I think I had some issues in an ant build file and when I split off the verifier it seemed to work. Using Ant in general might be a useful hint.

Answer (score 1):

I never post the solution. That day has finally arrived ;)

Download the JavaCard SDK. It contain a compiled version of the verifier. For that exemple that will be java_card_kit-2_2_1.

My files:

```
./
./java_card_kit-2_2_1/
./java2CAP.sh
./ValidApplet/
./ValidApplet/ValidApp.java
./verifyCAP.sh
```

java2CAP.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JC_HOME=./java_card_kit-2_2_1
export CLASSPATH=$JC_HOME/lib/apduio.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/apdutool.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/jcwde.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/converter.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/scriptgen.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/offcardverifier.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/api.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/capdump.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/:$JC_HOME/samples/classes:$CLASSPATH
PACKAGE=ValidApplet
CLASS=ValidApp
APPLET=$CLASS.java
PACKAGE_AID=0x46:0x56:0x55:0x4c:0x4e:0x54:0x45:0x53:0x54:0x53
APPLET_AID=0x46:0x56:0x55:0x4c:0x4e:0x54:0x45:0x53:0x54:0x53:0x41:0x70:0x70
javac -g -source 1.3 -target 1.1  $PACKAGE/$APPLET
java com.sun.javacard.converter.Converter -nobanner -out CAP -exportpath $JC_HOME/api_export_files -applet $APPLET_AID $CLASS $PACKAGE $PACKAGE_AID 1.0 -i
```

verifyCAP.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JC_HOME=./java_card_kit-2_2_1
export CLASSPATH=$JC_HOME/lib/apduio.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/apdutool.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/jcwde.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/converter.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/scriptgen.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/offcardverifier.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/api.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/capdump.jar:$JC_HOME/lib/:$JC_HOME/samples/classes:$CLASSPATH

export CAPP_PATH=./ValidApplet/javacard
export CAPP_NAME=ValidApplet.cap

java -classpath $JC_HOME/lib/offcardverifier.jar com.sun.javacard.offcardverifier.Verifier $JC_HOME/api_export_files/javacard/framework/javacard/framework.exp $JC_HOME/api_export_files/java/lang/javacard/lang.exp $JC_HOME/api_export_files/javacard/security/javacard/security.exp $CAPP_PATH/$CAPP_NAME
```

./ValidApplet/ValidApp.java:

```
package ValidApplet;

import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;

public class ValidApp extends Applet //implements PIN
{
    final static byte TEST_CLA = (byte)0x77;

    public static class TestClassStatic {};

    protected ValidApp()
    {
        register();
    }

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength)
    {
        new ValidApp();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {
        byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();

        try {
            if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == TEST_CLA) {
                test((byte)4, (short)2);
            } else {
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        } catch (ISOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```